# Based on cell value ,delete Entire row

Tags: excel, vba

I want to match Cell value with Sheet name if true keep else delete the entire row

```
For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
ws.Activate
index = index + 1
If index < 10 Then
    irow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    temp = ws.Name
    newtemp = Replace(temp, " ", "#0")
For J = 2 To irow
If Cells(irow, 1) <> newtemp Then
ActiveSheet.Cells(J, 1).EntireRow.Delete
```

Comment: You did not describe what is wrong with the code you currently have.

Comment: What the relation with your other question? "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55514473/based-on-cell-value-delete-entire-row"

Comment: When deleting rows loop backwards. It might help to post more of your code and do as hidden_4003 suggests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets '<-Loop worksheets

        With ws

            LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row '<- Get the Lastrow of column A. Change if needed

            For i = LastRow To 1 Step -1 '<- Loop from Lastrow to row 1
                If .Range("A" & i).Value <> Replace(ws.Name, " ", "#0") Then
                    .Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
                End If
            Next i

        End With

    Next ws

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

In your loop `If Cells(irow, 1) <> newtemp` is not referring to the loop variable.

Get in the habit of declaring your variables, and using Option Explicit.

There is no need to activate each sheet.

This has a few guesses as not sure of all the details.

```
Sub x()

Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, Index As Long, irow As Long, newtemp As String, j As Long

Set wb = ThisWorkbook '??

For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
    Index = Index + 1
    If Index < 10 Then
        irow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        newtemp = Replace(ws.name, " ", "#0")
        For j = irow To 2 Step -1
            If ws.Cells(j, 1) <> newtemp Then
                ws.Cells(j, 1).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next j
    End If
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Dear sir, this code take long time for processing, can we use autofilter method and Delete Hidden row only.

Comment: Example : i will filter Data with Sheet Name and Delete only hidden data